# How to add line breaks to bootstrap popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to break text into new lines but `<br/>` and `/n` are not working .

Here is my code:

```
 <a id="contact-seller" class="btn redB seller-btn" 
  data-confirm="By contacting this seller, you are automatically share your 
  profile information as well.<br/>Would you like to proceed?">
     Contact
 </a>
```

How do I break the `data-confirm` line with for example CSS?

Comment: Do you have a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us?

Comment: No. i dnt have both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-html="true"` to your markup like this:

```
 <a id="contact-seller" class="btn redB seller-btn" data-html="true"
                  data-confirm="By contacting this seller, you are automatically share your profile information as well.<br/>
                  Would you like to proceed?">
                   Contact
               </a>
```

Comment: I have added data-html="true" but </br> text is shown with text in popup.

Comment: Can you please post your codes in jsfiddle and I will check it out for you